# Email links from Stack Overflow Careers not working

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I recieved an email from SO Careers about currently looking for job status. Email notifies about my CV status, and ask me about update it status if needed (from active looking to smth other). Its OK with email itself BUT. Email has two links: *I'm still actively looking* and *Update status*. Non of these two links are working. They actully redirects to SO but it shows me **Oops! Something Bad Happened!** screen with a fun image

Is it OK with this email links?

Example of picture:

[image: Oops]

Email text:

***We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.
Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, http://meta.stackoverflow.com***

**Update**

I've registered on another StackExchande site - `Area51` and I received email that asked about email verification. When I clicked on verify link I received the same result with error page. But interesting point here is that I received this email on 2 email boxes (they are really my and both assigned here). when I tried to verify another email box it was done successfully. Problem occurred with `gmail` box and for careers site this problem is also with `gmail` box.

Maybe I should post it to global meta - I do not know is it good idea or not. I hope this update would be helpful

Comment: I believe this has been fixed. If not, please reply here with the broken URLs (you can replace any Ids in the URL with placeholder values), or email them to us at careers@stackoverflow.com and reference this post.